# How to capture a field instance during django-import-export upload

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-import-export

I'd like to import data into my resource minus the school field because the logged in user already belongs to a specific school. How would I do it without having the `school` field in my excel???

```
class uploadStudents(LoginRequiredMixin,View):
    context = {}
    def get(self,request):
        form = UploadStudentsForm()
        self.context['form'] = form
        return render(request,'upload.html',self.context)

    def post(self, request):
        form = UploadStudentsForm(request.POST , request.FILES)
        data_set = Dataset()
        if form.is_valid():
            file = request.FILES['file']
            extension = file.name.split(".")[-1].lower()
            resource = ImportStudentsResource()
            if extension == 'csv':
                data = data_set.load(file.read().decode('utf-8'), format=extension)
            else:
                data = data_set.load(file.read(), format=extension)
            result = resource.import_data(data_set, dry_run=True, collect_failed_rows=True, raise_errors=True)
            if result.has_validation_errors() or result.has_errors():
                messages.success(request,f'Errors experienced during import.')
                print("error", result.invalid_rows)
                self.context['result'] = result
                return redirect('import_students')                
            else:
                result = resource.import_data(data_set, dry_run=False, raise_errors=False)
                self.context['result'] = None
                messages.success(request,f'Students uploaded successfully.')                
        else:
            self.context['form'] = UploadStudentsForm()

        return render(request, 'upload.html', self.context)
```

The resource

```
class ImportStudentsResource(resources.ModelResource):
    school = fields.Field(attribute = 'school',column_name='school', widget=ForeignKeyWidget(School, 'name'))
    klass = fields.Field(attribute = 'klass',column_name='class', widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Klass, 'name'))
    stream = fields.Field(attribute = 'stream',column_name='stream', widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Stream, 'name'))
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('school','student_id','name','year','klass','stream')
        import_id_fields = ('student_id',)
        import_order = ('school','student_id','name','year','klass','stream')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either remove 'school' from your 'fields' declaration, or add it to the 'exclude' list.

[docs](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html?highlight=exclude#customize-resource-options)

**Edit**

To include a `school_id` which is associated with the logged in user, you'll need to create the Resource with this `school_id`:

Resource

```
class ImportStudentsResource(resources.ModelResource):

    def __init__(self, school_id):
        super().__init__()
        self.school_id = school_id

    def before_save_instance(self, instance, using_transactions, dry_run):
        instance.school_id = self.school_id
```

post()

```
def post(self, request):
    # skipped existing code
    school_id = get_school_id_from_logged_in_user(self.request)
    resource = ImportStudentsResource(school_id)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Matthew Hegarty