# How to uniquely identify a model instance in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-import-export

I have  program that keeps book records for different schools I have a Student model that enables each school to upload the students from an excel. I however get an error because already there are two schools each having form 1 form 2 and form 3. It returns MultipleObjectsReturned error.
Setting the filed as unique also does not allow other schools to create the same klass.
How is it that I can be able to uniquely identify every instannce ok Klass model so it returns no error.

get() returned more than one Klass -- it returned 2!

```
class ImportStudentsResource(resources.ModelResource):
    school = fields.Field(attribute = 'school',column_name='school', widget=ForeignKeyWidget(School, 'name'))
    klass = fields.Field(attribute = 'klass',column_name='class', widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Klass, 'name'))
    stream = fields.Field(attribute = 'stream',column_name='stream', widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Stream, 'name'))
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('school','student_id','name','year','klass','stream')
        import_id_fields = ('student_id',)
        import_order = ('school','student_id','name','year','klass','stream')

class uploadStudents(LoginRequiredMixin,View):
    context = {}
    def get(self,request):
        form = UploadStudentsForm()
        self.context['form'] = form
        return render(request,'libman/upload_student.html',self.context)

    def post(self, request):
        form = UploadStudentsForm(request.POST , request.FILES)
        data_set = Dataset()
        if form.is_valid():
            file = request.FILES['file']
            extension = file.name.split(".")[-1].lower()
            resource = ImportStudentsResource()
            if extension == 'csv':
                data = data_set.load(file.read().decode('utf-8'), format=extension)
            else:
                data = data_set.load(file.read(), format=extension)
            result = resource.import_data(data_set, dry_run=True, collect_failed_rows=True, raise_errors=True)
            if result.has_validation_errors() or result.has_errors():
                messages.success(request,f'Errors experienced during import.')
                print("error", result.invalid_rows)
                self.context['result'] = result
                return redirect('upload_students')                
            else:
                result = resource.import_data(data_set, dry_run=False, raise_errors=False)
                self.context['result'] = None
                messages.success(request,f'Students uploaded successfully.')                
        else:
            self.context['form'] = UploadStudentsForm()

        return render(request, 'libman/upload_student.html', self.context)

class Student(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    YEAR = [(str(a), str(a)) for a in range(now.year-2, now.year+2)]
    year = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices = YEAR)
    student_id = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True)
    klass = models.ForeignKey(Klass,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stream = models.ForeignKey(Stream,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Could you share your get() query that raises the MultipleObjectsReturned error?

Comment: I only have the view, the resource and the model that are already in the question.....Did I not get your concern properly??

Comment: I'm getting, return self.get_queryset(value, row, *args, **kwargs).get(**{self.field: val}) that is indicated to come from import_export/widgets.py

Comment: I'd advise you to use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together that is why I asked you this question. 
But It looks like you're only passing one named argument to get(). So you don't need unique_together. Making that self.field unique=True should fulfil your need.

Comment: I'm lost more on this, please..

Comment: Can you debug and find out what is the value of self.field?

Comment: self.field prints the klass name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import your data, the logic cannot uniquely identify a unique instance of 'klass'. You are using the 'name' attribute of the foreign key relationship to class, however as you said, this 'name' field cannot uniquely identify an instance of the Klass, hence you get the `MultipleObjectsReturned` error.

The solution is to create a subclass of `ForeignKeyWidget` which uses an overridden `get_queryset()` which can uniquely identify the Klass.  You will need to use an additional parameter which can be added to the query.  I'm guessing that `school_id` might work (but I don't know your data model).

```py
class KlassForeignKeyWidget(widgets.ForeignKeyWidget):
    """
    Custom widget to lookup a Klass instance
    """
    def __init__(
        self,
        school_id,
        field="name",
        *args,
        **kwargs,
    ):
        super().__init__(self.model, field=field, *args, **kwargs)
        self.school_id = school_id

    def get_queryset(self, value, row, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.model.objects.filter(school_id=self.school_id)
```

Then you'll have to declare this custom widget in your Resource:

```py
class ImportStudentsResource(resources.ModelResource):

    def __init__(self, school_id):
        super().__init__()
        self.school_id = school_id

        self.fields["klass"] = fields.Field(
            attribute="klass",
            column_name="class",
            widget=myapp.widgets.KlassForeignKeyWidget(
                school_id,
            ),
        )
```

Then when you instantiate the `ImportStudentsResource` [you pass in the `school_id`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67538344/39296).